# Multiple Strings into Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to add Strings dynamically into an ArrayList along with index position and then pass on the Arraylist as an extra in Intent.The process runs fine for first time and on next call to this activity would end up in Index out of bounds Exception. Please see the code below and suggest if this is a flaw in the code.

```
 private ArrayList<String> imagesUriArray=new ArrayList<>();
 static int imageIndex=-1;
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    // Some standard code goes here to capture the image and store it...
        image = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), image);
        selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        final String UriString = new String(selectedImage.toString());
        imageIndex++;

 195:   imagesUriArray.add(imageIndex,UriString);
        Intent email = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, EmailActivity.class);
        email.putExtra("picture", imageInByte);
        email.putStringArrayListExtra("Uri", imagesUriArray);
        startActivity(email);


Logcat says:
    20320-20320/com.example.kittu.ClientLync E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.kittu.ClientLync/com.example.kittu.ClientLync.ScanActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:152)
        at com.example.kittu.ClientLync.ScanActivity.onActivityResult(ScanActivity.java:195)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
```

Comment: you are using  `static int imageIndex=-1;`   This seems little risky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ArrayList<String> imagesUriArray=new ArrayList<>();
static int imageIndex=-1;
..
imageIndex++;
imagesUriArray.add(imageIndex,UriString);
```

The first time `onActivityResult` is called, `imageIndex` is -1, so after incrementing it, you are adding an item to the first index (0) of the list.

However, since `imageIndex` is static, the next time `onActivityResult` is called for a different object, `imageIndex` is 0 even though the list is empty, so you try to add an element to index 1 of an empty List, which throws the index out of bounds exception. If you change `imageIndex` to be non-static, the problem will be resolved.

Another option to avoid the exception you are getting is to change `imagesUriArray.add(imageIndex,UriString);` to `imagesUriArray.add(UriString);`. This will add the element to the next available index of the list.

Comment: Thanks @Eran. If i change it to imagesUriArray.add(UriString); will i be able to retrieve in the order i inserted? I am more concerned about the order of insertion and retrieval

Comment: @Kittu `imagesUriArray.add(UriString)` always adds to the end of the List, so yes, you'll be able to retrieve the elements in the order you inserted them.

Comment: After making it a non-static variable, the problem now is image index is 0 always.I tried with imagesUriArray.add(UriString) and now the arraylist is always of size 1. Any guess on what my mistake is

Comment: @Kittu It's hard to say without knowing when `onActivityResult` is called and on which object. If it's never called more than once on the same object, the size of the List will never be larger than 1.

Comment: Oops Eran. But thanks a lot for your help.I fixed the issue.Code is running as required.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing an invalid index in the arraylist, for example, if your arraylist is empty and you try to insert in the index = 1 it will throw you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: :Thank you.But I am inserting index along with String but not the index alone.Does it matter?

Comment: @Kittu yes it matters, why not sorting while inserting? would be easier

Comment: @Kittu: Remove static modifier from ImageIndex.

Answer (score 0):

According to your stack trace, you're seeing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not an NPE.

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

You're seeing this because you've tried to insert in the list outside the allowed range. The allowed range is zero to the length of the list, inclusive. In this case, you've tried to add an element at index 1, but the list has zero elements.

From the documentation for [ArrayList.add(int index, E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-):

> public void add(int index,
>         E element)
>
> ...
>
> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

Answer (score 0):

Try this , you are accessing the wrong index while inserting

```
 private ArrayList<String> imagesUriArray=new ArrayList<>();
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        imagesUriArray.add(imageIndex,UriString);
        Intent email = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, EmailActivity.class);
        email.putExtra("picture", imageInByte);
        email.putStringArrayListExtra("Uri", imagesUriArray);
        startActivity(email);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)
read the documentation.
Explicitly is written that the add(int, E) method throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to access to an index that it's not valid. Look in your log console it gives to you an

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
```

It's because you are trying to access to index 1, that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is you are using

`static int imageIndex=-1;`

So first time it works because it increments and becomes 0, while size of ArrayList is 0;

On next call, it increments again and index becomes 1, while List is again of size 0.

So try removing static modifier